# How to create customise Zabbix Dashboard to monitor Cameras

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-api, zabbix-custom-reports

In one of my current project, we are using lot of devices like 500+ Cameras, 100+  LPUs and so on.
I want to check the health of each (ping them (IP ping) every few seconds and if no response it is down). So this way I want to monitor the devices. This way I'll get to know which cameras/devices are down and what was each downtime/uptime and hence define their health.

Also I want to display the same on Dashboard.

How can I achieve this using Zabbix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Map, even show different colors for OK or Problem state. You can add a Map to a Dashboard.

See https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/monitoring/maps

In the following example i selected all hosts in a Host Group, showing the Status application, which contains the ICMP triggers.

Result:
[image: map showing items, red for errors]

Configuration:
[image: map configuration window]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am totally new to zabbix and I am using 6.2 ZABBIX VERSION and hence cannot find the Icon SemaphoreGreen and SemaphoreRed, Is there a way to add this? and also can you help me setup things in Zabbix?

Comment: you can add images in Administration > General > Images   https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.2/en/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/administration/general?hl=Images%2Cimages#images